# PyQt GUI based CRUD application

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I am new to the world of PyQt.I am using PyQt designer for designing the UI and coding to provide functionality in it.But unfortunately I am getting confused to link with the UI.By importing the class we generally doing in examples.But when I try my own code its not happening.

Any hints for how designer and other parts interacts will be super helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *What* "is not happening"? Do you get an error, and if so, what does it say?

Comment: When i run the file,common problem is
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ImageViewer.py", line 9, in <module>
    class ImageViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow, ImageViewerUI.Ui_mainWindow):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Ui_mainWindow'
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
class ImageViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow, ImageViewerUI.Ui_MainWindow):
```

because by default pyuic4 create the class Ui_MainWindow and **not** Ui_mainWindow

Comment: Thanks alot :) It is working,now I can understand how the ui py file interacts with the functional file .

Answer (score -1):

```
winBase, winForm = uic.loadUiType("mainWindow.ui") # this is the 
                                                     file created whith Qt Designer
class Window(winBase, winForm):
   def __init__(self, parent = None)
     super(winBase, self).__init__(parent)
     self.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: While this is certainly useful, it would be even better with some sort of context, or a manual link perhaps?